# How to pass list of objects to Spring Controller for multiple row inserts?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jdbctemplate

There is a jsp which outputs a HTML5 page. The HTML5 has two buttons - "Add" and "Save". HTML5 local storage feature is used to store offline data.

"Add" button adds a record when clicked. So if user fills the fields on the jsp page 5 times and clicks the "Add" button 5 times, 5 records are added to the HTML5 table. When "Add" button is clicked, a javascript is run which adds the record to a result set. So for 5 clicks the javascript result set contains 5 records.

"Save" button, when clicked,  must insert all the 5 records from the javascript result set to the Oracle database. To do this the list of records from result set must be passed to the Spring controller.

The Spring controller has been coded using batchUpdate api.

```
public void insertListOfPojos(final List<MyPojo> myPojoList) {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO "
        + "MY_TABLE "
        + "(FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3) "
        + "VALUES " + "(?,?,?)";

    getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i)
            throws SQLException {

            MyPojo myPojo = myPojoList.get(i);
            ps.setString(1, myPojo.getField1());
            ps.setString(2, myPojo.getField2());
            ps.setString(3, myPojo.getField3());

        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return myPojoList.size();
        }
    });

}
```

The question is - How do you pass the records from the javascript result set to the Spring controller so that it is available to controller's "myPojoList" when the "Add" button is clicked?

Comment: How do you submit the data? Is it an AJAX call? Is an HTML form filled via Javascript?

Comment: It is an HTML page with input fields. When user enters values in these fields and hits "Add" button, javascript in the HTML page inserts these values into HTML5 table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have couple of thoughts

1. Form that 5 records into a json string and post to the controller and unmarshall the json to object and store in Oracle.
2. Form that 5 records to a delimited string some thing like `id1,name1,address1|id2,name2,address2`..etc. In the server side you can tokenize and store in the Oracle.

JSON has standard format so that will be better option. The javascript that is used to store in HTML5 can be used to form this string in the client and once submit read from the client and push to the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not too familiar with JSON.How do you put the records into json? And how do you post the json object to controller? Could you please give little hint of code snippet.

Comment: typically you can see the json samples here http://json.org/example.html. The way you can form your object is [ {"field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2" }, {"field1" : "value3", "field2" : "value4"} ]. You can form this kind of json string in the jsp page using jquery and post this whole string to the server. There you can use either Jackson or Gson library to unmarshall the json to your pojo object. you can take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ as well.

Comment: Thanks again. I already have the jQuery object "myobj", this jQuery object has all the 5 records in it. Is it not possible to send this entire object to the controller? Would these kind of code work:     var json_text = JSON.stringify(myobj) OR $.toJSON(myObj);

Comment: Yes that should work, please make sure to go through this http://www.json.org/js.html. There is one more option like jQuery.stringifyJSON. Also the myObj should be in a valid structure for the stringify to convert it to json. Check this fiddle for more insight http://jsfiddle.net/qmacro/W54hy/